# Dialog does not show up after 30 seconds on Homescreen

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I wanted to make an App where a dialaog appears after 30seconds on the Homescreen. The idea is that you click on enable alert dialog in the app and close the app and go to the Homescreen. However, when I click on the button the dialog does not appear. Is it a problem with the main class? I tried to implement the code from this link: http://www.feelzdroid.com/2014/11/how-to-display-custom-dialog-on-android-home-screen.html

Here is my code for the mainActivity class:

```
 package com.example.homescreendialog;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.app.AlarmManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button mAlertButton;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mAlertButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ID_Alert_dialog);
            mAlertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
    
                    //Alarm manager
    
                    long timestamp = 30000;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertDialogReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                            167, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    
                    AlarmManager amgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
    
                    amgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timestamp,
                            mAlarmSender);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the code for the dialogClass to build the dialog:

```
 package com.example.homescreendialog;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    
    public class AlertDialogClass extends Activity {
        AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDlgBuilder;
        AlertDialog mAlertDialog;
        View mDialogView = null;
        Button mOKBtn, mCancelBtn;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    
            mAlertDlgBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            mDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            mOKBtn = (Button)mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.ID_Ok);
            mCancelBtn = (Button)mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.ID_Cancel);
            mOKBtn.setOnClickListener(mDialogbuttonClickListener);
            mCancelBtn.setOnClickListener(mDialogbuttonClickListener);
            mAlertDlgBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            mAlertDlgBuilder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            mAlertDlgBuilder.setView(mDialogView);
            mAlertDialog = mAlertDlgBuilder.create();
            mAlertDialog.show(); 
        }
      View.OnClickListener mDialogbuttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.ID_Ok) {
                    mAlertDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                } else if(v.getId() == R.id.ID_Cancel) {
                    mAlertDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

This is the code for the AlertDialogReceiveClass:

```
package com.example.homescreendialog;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlertDialogReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        alarmIntent.setClass(context, AlertDialogClass.class);
        alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did u registered this broadcast reciever in android manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

You clearly followed everything in the link you provided but forgot to add the receiver tag in the manifest file that's where the android ignore you're receiver when you leave the app.

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.homescreendialog.AlertDialogReceiver"/>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but I thought I added the receiver tag in the manifest file. It is above <activity android:name=".MainActivity">. Or where should I add the tag? :)

Comment: I guess you're supposed wait half minute to get the dialog as it will not instantly show as you set the time. when you click the button and completely close the app from recents.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I tried to make the dialog appear after 10 seconds. Unfortunatly it did not work. I tried to let the app be open and after these 10 seconds, the app crashed.